# Use Reduce to call list of functions

Tags: r, filter

I would like to use a list of filters on a vector. My question is, how can I use Reduce (or other base R standard-function) to do what the recursive function is doing (=applying all functions in `filter_list` and logical-AND-connections) in this example:

```
my_vec <- c("AAffff1", "AAafszx223", "AAasfe2XX", "uuse3", "AA232fiserf", "ffse1211", "766", "AA33")

filter_list <- list(
  f_1 = function(x) {substr(x, 1, 2) == "AA"},
  f_2 = function(x) {grepl("\\d{3,}", x)},
  f_3 = function(x) {nchar(x) >= 5})

my_call <- function(fun_list, x) {
  if (length(fun_list) == 1) {
    fun_list[[1]](x) 
  } else {
    my_call(fun_list[-length(fun_list)], x) & fun_list[[length(fun_list)]](x)
  }
}
my_vec[my_call(filter_list, my_vec)]
# [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf" --> ok

my_vec[Reduce(function(f, ...) f(...), filter_list, my_vec, right = TRUE)]
# character(0) --> wrong
```

Comment: "...to do what the recursive function is doing..." which is what? Please explain what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: The recursive calls each function in `filter_list` and checks if each condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some alternatives. All use only base R.  (2) uses `Reduce`.  (4) is has the shortest code. (3) seems particularly simple.

**1) outer** You don't actually need `Reduce` for this.  Use `outer` to create a logical matrix whose ith row and jth column is TRUE if the ith function applied to the jth element of `my_vec` is TRUE and then from that use `apply` to create a logical vector whose jth element is TRUE if all elements in the jth column are TRUE and finally subscript `my_vec` by that.

```
call_fun <- function(fun, x) fun(x)
my_vec[ apply(outer(filter_list, my_vec, Vectorize(call_fun)), 2, all) ]
## "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

**2) Reduce** On the other hand we certainly could use `Reduce`. Create a function which takes a character string and calls each function in `filter_list` on it using `Reduce` to AND the results.  Then use `Filter` to extract those elements of `my_vec` for which application of that function gives TRUE.

```
Filter(function(x) Reduce(`&`, lapply(filter_list, do.call, list(x))), my_vec)
## [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

**3) all**  Actually we could eliminate `Reduce` in (2) by using `all` and nearly identical code.

```
Filter(function(x) all(sapply(filter_list, do.call, list(x))), my_vec)
## [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

**4)** Another variation is the following. `sapply` creates a matrix similar but transposed from the matrix in (1) and then we apply `all` to its rows and subscript.

```
my_vec[ apply(sapply(filter_list, do.call, list(my_vec)), 1, all) ]
[1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

**5) double sapply** This one uses ideas from the above but is a bit more symmetric in using a double `sapply`:

```
my_vec[ sapply(my_vec, function(x) all(sapply(filter_list, do.call, list(x)))) ]
## [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to use `Reduce` would be:

```
my_vec[Reduce('&',lapply(filter_list,
                     function(f) {f(my_vec)}))]
```

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` option.

- `invoke_map` takes a list of functions as a first argument, and maps those functions to the arguments in `...`.
- `reduce('&')` returns a vector which is `TRUE` iff all the corresponding entries in the LHS list's vectors are `TRUE` (same as `Reduce('&'`).
- `keep(.x = vec, .p = logical_vec)` is the same as `vec[logical_vec]`.

--

```
library(purrr)

invoke_map(filter_list, x = my_vec) %>%
  reduce(`&`) %>% 
  keep(.x = my_vec)

# [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

Comment: I think I should take a closer look at ìnvoke_map`, but can only accept 1 answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

```
library(purrr)
my_vec[reduce(map(filter_list, ~.(my_vec)), `&`)]
# [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"

my_vec[reduce(filter_list, ~ .x & .y(my_vec), .init = TRUE)]
# [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"

my_vec[apply(map_dfr(filter_list, ~.(my_vec)),1,all)]
# [1] "AAafszx223"  "AA232fiserf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version, although it feels like a derivative of G. Grothendieck 1st answer:

```
library(magrittr)

sapply(filter_list, mapply, my_vec) %>% apply(., 1, all) %>% my_vec[.]
```